# c++ temp conversion issue always same result

Tags: c++

New to this, am trying to do a c++ code to turn farrenheit into celcius.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    double degreesF{0};
    double degreesC{0};
    double temp;
    //Define relationship between C and F
    degreesC = 5.0/9*(degreesF -32);
    //Prompt user for degreesF
    cout << "Enter the temperate in degrees F: ";
    cin >> temp;
    degreesC = temp;

    //Report the result
    cout << temp << endl;
    return 0;

};
```

But it doesn't output correct result. Think I need a temp variable because otherwise degreesC is assigned a value before the user inputs a value and the result is always -17.7778. Is there a proper elegant way to do this? ThankYou.

Comment: `//Define relationship between C and F` - this comment is lying.

Comment: You need to do the calculation after the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in

```
degreesC = 5.0/9*(degreesF -32);
```

beacuse `=` is assignements operator in C and C++. This is not a definition of relation. And it done when `degreesF` is `0`.

Later

```
degreesC = temp;
```

`degreesC` vlaue is replaced with value of `temp`. No calculation, just copying of data.

And the main problem is in

```
cout << temp << endl;
```

where must be

```
cout << degreesC << endl;
```

Try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    double degreesC = 0.0;
    double degreesF;

    //Prompt user for degreesF
    cout << "Enter the temperate in degrees F: ";
    cin >> degreesF;
    // Calculation
    degreesC = 5.0/9*(degreesF -32);
    //Report the result
    cout << degreesC << endl;
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Gave you the tick for your explanation of where i had gone astray.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    double degreesF = 0;
    double degreesC = 0;

    //Prompt user for degreesF
    cout << "Enter the temperate in degrees F: ";
    cin >> degreesF;

    //Define relationship between C and F
    degreesC = 5.0/9*(degreesF -32);

    //Report the result
    cout << degreesC << endl;
    return 0;
};
```

Is that what you wanna do?

Comment: thx that works. This app is available for 9.99$ on android market place, discount since u helped me ;)

Answer (score 0):

in c++ `=` is an assignment operator (it makes what's on the left hand side logically equal to what's on the right hand side).

It's obvious that you want to declare that `degreesC` represents a conversion *function* rather than an assignment.

Here's one way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    double degreesF{0};
    double temp;
    //Define relationship between C and F
    auto degreesC = [](double degreesF) { return 5.0/9*(degreesF -32); };
    //Prompt user for degreesF
    cout << "Enter the temperate in degrees F: ";
    cin >> degreesF;
    temp = degreesC(degreesF);

    //Report the result
    cout << temp << endl;
    return 0;

};
```

example I/O:

```
Enter the temperate in degrees F: 89
31.6667
```

Comment: TY for the example. It seems overly complicated. It doesn't compile without errors: 'degreesC' does not name a type. degressC was not declared in this scope.

Comment: @DanielKratz you're probably not compiling with -std=c++11. lambda functions are a c++11 addition.

Comment: Cheers that fixed it.